# Network Flow Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have got a problem like this:

We are given a bipartite graph. For e.g.

```
A1 B1
A2 B2
A3 B3
A4
```

And here is the adjacency list representation (assume graph is bidirectional)

```
B1 -> A2, A3
B2 -> A2, A3, A4
B3 -> A1
```

Final result should be that all nodes in the left side (As) have exactly 1 incoming edge and at the same time - we need to minimize the maximum number of edges that need to go out of individual Bs nodes. In this case the answer would be:

```
B3 can connect to A1
B2 can connect to A2, A4
B1 can connect to A3
```

So here the maximum number of edges that need to out of a single Bs node is 2. We cannot cover all As and at the same time have a B node not having 2 edges going out of it to cover As.

Another example:

```
A1 B1
A2 B2
A3 B3
A4 B4

B1 -> A1, A2, A3
B2 -> A1, A2, A3, A4
B3 -> A1, A2, A3
B4 -> A1, A2, A3
```

In this case the answer would be:

```
B1 can connect to A1
B2 can connect to A4
B3 can connect to A3
B2 can connect to A2
```

This way we will cover all the As exactly once and at the same time we have minimized the maximum number of edges that need to go out of individual B's. So here the maximum number of edges that need to out of a single Bs node is 1.

Another example:

```
A1 B1
A2 B2
A3 B3
A4
A5
A6

B1 -> A6
B2 -> A1, A2, A3, A4, A5
B3 ->
```

In this case the answer would be 5 i.e. the maximum number of edges that need to go out of a single Bs is 5. Can't do less than that.

I have implemented basic ford fulkerson algorithm and I know this is also network flow but don't know how to relate to it.

It will be great if someone can give some hint about the graph.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding an optimal solution - with all B's have at most one out edge (if one exists) is simple:

- Add a source and a sink to the graph. The source will have an out
  edge with capacity 1 to all vertices on B's list.
- All `(B,A)` edges will have a capacity of 1.
- All A's will have an out edge with capacity 1 to the sink.
- Now, running a flow algorithm will yield the maximal number of
  vertices in A that can be covered with each B having only a single
  out going edge (optimal solution, if one exists)

---

**EDIT:**

Now, based on the above idea, and since you are trying to minimize the **maximum number of edges** from a single B to A (and NOT the total number of them, as I previously thought), an optimal solution is simple:

```
while there is no coverage:
   set capacity(source,b_k) = increase_size() (for each b_k in B)
   run max flow algorithm on the graph suggested above
return last flow found
```

Complexity is `O(E*V*#iterations)` (In this problem `f <= V`, thus the complexity if ford-fulkerson is `O(EV)`), where `#iterations` can be done linear in the minimal maximum number you seek, or using exponential increase, and then binary search on the range (as suggested by Evkeny Kluev), in log of this number.

Since `E=O(V)` in bipartite graph, we get total of `O(V^2*log(V))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Amit. This is what my understanding is - after I have constructed my graph (and ignoring binary search for now, i will go linear :-) ) - Say there are three Bs so source connects to B1, B2 and B3. I should set the edge capacity of source : B1 to 1 - run max flow - see how many As are covered - then set the edge capacity of source : B2 to 1 - run max flow - see how many As are covered then source : B3 to 1 then source : B1 to 2 source : B2 to 2 then source : B2 to 2 then source : B3 to 2 ! Is that right?

Comment: Also what if I have a graph where every B connect to every A? In that that case as soon as I run the max flow algorithm for the first time, all As will be covered. However the answer in this case is 1 i.e. each B only need to connect to 1 A to cover everything up! Let me know if I have missed something. Thanks.

Comment: @VVV: No, set ALL of the edges to B's with capacity of one in the first iteration: (source,B1), (source,B2), (source,B3) - all set to 1 in the first iteration. In the second iteration set them all to 2, and in the 3rd to 3, ....

Comment: @VVV: If you have a B which is connected to all A's, if the flow to this B is set to 1 (as it is), it can cover at most 1 A.

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't think enough. Even though we have a B node connected to all As if the edge weight from source to B is 1, only 1 A can be covered. Alright, I will implement this and see how it goes. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

Connect all A's to one common sink node with edges of capacity 1. Connect all B's to one common source node with edges of variable capacity `C`.

Find maximal network flow in this graph, increasing `C` when not every A is covered and decreasing it otherwise. Which means find optimal value for `C` using binary search.

Comment: Thanks Evgeny Kluev for your time ! Can you explain as to what do you mean by increasing capacity here? If I have a graph where all Bs connect to all As and I set C to 1 for 1 of the edges connecting source to some B node, all edges will be covered. However the answer in this case is 1 as each B needs to connect to only 1 A. Thanks.

Comment: As you've already got this explanation from amit, I'll only add some details about binary search. For the first iteration you may set `C` to some expected value, for example, 2. Then you apply one-sided binary search and increase `C` like this: 2->4->8->16... As soon as all As are covered, you continue with normal binary search: 8->6->5. Alternatively, you can skip one-sided search, set `C` to the number of As and perform normal binary search.